# JS: Including a variable name into another variable name possible?

Tags: javascript

So for example I am trying to do a for loop in JS

```
               for (var i=0;i<result.length;i++){
                    var btn[i] = document.createElement("BUTTON");
                    var t[i] = document.createTextNode("CLICK ME");
                    btn.appendChild(t[i]);
                }
```

the `i` being the delimiter, is it possible to append it to another variable name like above when I try to create an element? Just to make the variable name unique. Right now I am trying with the square brackets and it's giving me an error saying unexpected []. Any help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to create new variables for each one? Can you not just store them all in an array?

Comment: [Learn more about arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Array_Object).

Answer (score 0):

In browsers (I've never done any [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js) stuff) the global scope lives in the window object.

```
bla = 'test';
window['bla'] == 'test';
```

This means that you can create a variable say `test1` like this:

```
window[bla + 1] = 'foo';
```